# unable to run flask app as a docker image

Tags: docker, flask, dockerfile

I'm a complete beginner in docker in windows 10 and I have a flask project with some html templates inside a directory . I create a dockerfile and insert it inside my directory and then I build a docker image to run . However Instead of running my docker image I get the error `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"python\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.` which I do not understand or know how to solve .

My dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER bill<bill@gmailcom>
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip 
RUN pip3 install flask pymongo
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR "/MovieFlix2020_E17136_SKENTOS_VASILIS"
CMD ["python", "webservice.py", "--host", "127.0.0.1", "--port", "5000"]
```

I build the image inside my `"/MovieFlix2020_E17136_SKENTOS_VASILIS"` directory with `docker build -t flask .`
The image is succesfully built but I get the warning :
[image]

And in the end with `run flask` which has to run my newly created image I get the error I wrote above .

I would appreciate your help with guiding me to solve this issue . Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Listening for connections on 127.0.0.1, also known as "localhost", allows connections only local connections. When you listen on 127.0.0.1 from within a container, only connections *from within that container* will work.

The fix is simple. Change "127.0.0.1" to "0.0.0.0".

Comment: In my flask app however I run it on 127.0.0.1 . Should I change it there or it doesn't matter ? Thank you for your answer

Comment: If you're running the flask app locally (not in a docker container), then either 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 will work, though the latter means that people who can connect to your computer can access the app. If that's not a risk, I'd change to 0.0.0.0 for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting says `"exec: \"python\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown"`. I think you got this error because your container has python3 installed but in your `CMD` parameters you are running `python` which by default will try to run version 2.7 of python in ubuntu.
Try replacing 
`CMD ["python", "webservice.py", "--host", "127.0.0.1", "--port", "5000"]`
with 
`CMD ["python3", "webservice.py", "--host", "127.0.0.1", "--port", "5000"]`.